# How to convert video into millisecond frames instead of converted from basic framerate using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, tensor

Hi  I am currently trying to convertvideos into millisecond frames using opencv python. The things is, right now I know how to convert the video based on it's frame rates, instead of millisecond. I don't know how to tweak the code in order to  convert the video into series of image from milliseconds rate.
I found my code on this stackoverflow:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('S001-100.avi')
count = 0
success = True
while success:
 vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,(count*1000))
 success,image=vidcap.read()

 last = cv2.imread("frame{}.png".format(count-1))
 if np.array_equal(image,last):
    break

 if not os.path.exists('imgvid'):
    os.makedirs('imgvid')

 cv2.imwrite("imgvid/frame%d.png" % count,image)
 print('{}.sec reading a new frame: {}'.format(count,success))
 count +=1
```

the reason I want to convert into millisecond is because I am trying to make facial expression pattern below than 1 seconds. hopefully there will be an answer for this.

Comment: The split into milliseconds will have no advantage over spliting on frames. In fact it will add a tiny latency when the new time slots start after a new frame has arrived. You will just get 30 to 40 identical frames in a row. You can be better than the camera.

Comment: @KlausD. Thak you for replied. Honestly saying, my project is based on micro-expressions. The micro-expression only happened below 1 second, which is around 0.02 to 0.04 seconds. That is why i need to chunk it into series of images in term of milliseconds. The expressions are very subtles, even my machine need to learned based on the transition of expression changes. If you know how to code it, please teach me

Comment: Your limitation is the frame rate of the camera/video. You won't get more frames than that. What do you expect to get when you make 1000 frames out of the let's say 25 frames from the camera or video?

Comment: I see. that's to bad I guesssed

Comment: I finally knnow how to get my desired output. for (count*1000), if change to (count*1), I will got 1000 frames per second. but, my project need to use (count*10), and I got 100 frames per second. that's all, thank you

Comment: So, you still haven't understood what I explained?

Comment: I get what you trying to say. the motion itself change over frame. but, there is a chance that I missed the fleeting expressions, since it happened around 200-400 milliseconds